# Automating Multiple User Account Creation in AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

I have an EC2 Ubuntu instance and I want to make around 100 accounts on it. I have generated all the necessary key-pairs using a Python Script. Now the challenge is to send the public keys to the corresponding user directories in an automated manner. I am on a Windows machine so ssh-copy-id does not seem to work and I cannot use that in a bash script.

Does anyone know the best way to tackle this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just do what `ssh-copy-id` does.

- SFTP or SSH to the host (e.g. using Paramiko).
- Create `.ssh` folder with right permissions, if it does not exist yet.
- Create `authorized_keys` with right permissions, if it does not exist yet.
- Append your public key to it.

Btw, googling *"ssh-copy-id in python"* reveals that there's Python implementation of `ssh-copy-id`:
https://pypi.org/project/sshcopyid/

Related question of Super User:
[Command to copy client public key to Windows OpenSSH SFTP/SSH server authorized keys file](https://superuser.com/q/1451241/213663)

Comment: Any feedback on this?